# How to replace keyboard output using python

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am not exactly sure how to word this question so I'll try to explain my problem here.

I am trying to code a program that reads text (for example an essay) from a txt file and then types each letter from that `txt` file as you type a letter on the keyboard (think those hacker games where you mash the keyboard and it looks like you're typing something that you are not).

Currently I am handling this by simply deleting the character right after but I noticed that I needed to add a delay for this to work with any stability whatsoever.  A delay of `0.05` works okay, but any lower is unstable and `0.05` is already far too much for my liking.  I also tried using `keyboard.press_and_release()` but this needed just as large of a delay without breaking.

I am using the keyboard module because it works on both Windows and Mac which is a must have.  I am also not exactly sure that I understand why this is happening especially with the press and release function so hopefully someone might know an answer or maybe a different module to use.  I have also tried `pyautogui` and that was even worse.

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
# only keyboard needs to be pip installed i think

if __name__ == '__main__':
    keyboard.wait("ctrl")
    time.sleep(2)
    inFile = open('Essay', 'r')
    while True:
        line = inFile.readline();
        # if line is empty meaning file is reached
        if not line:
            break
        while len(line) > 0:
            keyboard.read_key()
            time.sleep(0.05)
            keyboard.press("backspace")
            time.sleep(0.05)
            keyboard.press(line[0])
            line = line[1:len(line)]
            time.sleep(0.05)
        keyboard.press("enter")
```

Comment: simpler `line = line[1:]` . Or even simpler `for char in line: ... keyboard.press(char) ...`

Comment: simpler `for line in inFile:` without `if not line: break`.

Comment: I'm not sure but `keyboard` runs as separated thread and Python may need time to switch from main thread to another thread - because `Python` has `GIL` which allow to run only thread a time. Maybe you should check source code to see how it works.

Comment: do you have to do it with `keyboard`? If you run in current console then maybe `print()` it ? And use `\r` instead of `backspace`

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but it may help you. Install the PyPI package:

```
pip install keyboard
```

or clone the repository (no installation required, source files are sufficient):

```
git clone https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard
```

or download and extract the zip into your project folder.

Then check the API docs below to see what features are available.

**Example:**

```
import keyboard

keyboard.press_and_release('shift+s, space')

keyboard.write('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')

keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+a', print, args=('triggered', 'hotkey'))

# Press PAGE UP then PAGE DOWN to type "foobar".
keyboard.add_hotkey('page up, page down', lambda: keyboard.write('foobar'))

# Blocks until you press esc.
keyboard.wait('esc')

# Record events until 'esc' is pressed.
recorded = keyboard.record(until='esc')
# Then replay back at three times the speed.
keyboard.play(recorded, speed_factor=3)

# Type @@ then press space to replace with abbreviation.
keyboard.add_abbreviation('@@', 'my.long.email@example.com')

# Block forever, like `while True`.
keyboard.wait()
```

**Courtesy:** https://softans.com/how-to-replace-keyboard-output-using-python/

Comment: OP already uses `keyboard` so OP probably  already know all these information. OP needs to know why it needs so long delays.